# ActiveRecord select all columns from multiple tables after joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models `Article - :id, :name, :handle` `Comment - :id, :name, :article_id`

My query looks like `data = Article.select("articles.*, comments.*").joins("INNER JOIN comments on articles.id = comments.article_id")`

Now both the models have conflicting fields. Ideally I would want to be able to do something like `data.first.comments.name` or `data.first.articles.name`.

Note I am aware of option of doming something like `articles.name as article_name` but I have some tables with around 20 columns. So don't want to do that.

Comment: Why do would you want them both in the same result set? Why not fetch the articles and with `includes(:comments)`, eager load the comments?

Answer (score 0):

The example you are showing is barely utilising the Rails framework at all. It seems you are thinking to much of the database structure instead of thinking of the result as Ruby Objects.

Here is what I would suggest you do to get access to the data (since you are using Rails, I assume it is for a webpage so my example is for rendering an html.erb template):

```
# In controller
@articles = Article.includes(:comments)

# In views
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <h1><%= article.name %></h1>

  <% article.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><%= comment.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But if you just want all the column data into a big array or arrays (database style), you could do it like this

```
rows = Article.includes(:comments).inject([]) { |arr, article|
  article.comments.inject(arr) { |arr2, comment|
    arr2 << (article.attributes.values + comment.attributes.values)
  }
}
```

If you don't know how the inject method works, I really recommend to read up on it because it is a very useful tool.